# В чём отличие функции от метода в C++?

Tags: c++, функции, методы

На пути обучения C++ столкнулся с такими понятиями, как методы и функции и, собственно, не нахожу отличий между ними. Описываются они одинаково и идентичны по функциональности, так в чём отличия?

Comment: такое есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711189/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: спасибо, но мне интересны функции и методы конкретно в c++, а в том вопросе фигурирует java, думаю, некоторые отличия между языками есть

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Термин "метод" в стандарте С++ не используется. Это разговорное название для *функции-члена класса* (member function).

То есть если функция находится внутри класса - это метод. Если снаружи класса - просто функция.

Comment: Еще можно добавить, что существенное отличие в том, что у метода определена переменная `this`, а у обычной функции нет

Comment: @avp Это зависит от того, называть ли статические функции-члены методами. C одной стороны, я не слышал, чтобы кто-то их так называл, но [википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods) их относит к методам.

Comment: Да, про отсутствие `this` у них забыл. Конечно, они по своей сути являются функциями, только с немного специфической  областью видимости переменных. Впрочем, классификация явлений вещь, конечно, интересная, но не всегда практически ценная -)